# Button disappears on click, opt-in form appears. Cool effect. How to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to implement what happens on this page : http://yogatime.tv/

When you click "REQUEST INVITE", the button disappears, and a sleak opt-in form appears on its place. I checked the css and source code, couldn't sort this out.

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Thanks,
Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, they set the button style to "display:none" and at the same time they set the form style to "display:inline-block".

To make it look like a smooth transition, they are also changing the opacity of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening, is they fade-out the first box, put another element in it's place, then fade it in. Here's a basic example:

```js
document.getElementById('target_1').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('target_1').classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('target_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('target_2').classList.add('active');
  }, 600);/*time*/
};
```

```css
#target_1 {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 600ms ease;/*time*/
}
#target_1.active {
  opacity: 0;
}
#target_2 {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 600ms ease;/*time*/
}
#target_2.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="target_1">Div1</div>
<div id="target_2">Div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

https://jsfiddle.net/1xwvas49/3/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button id="target">Request Invite</button>
    <form id="result">
        <input id="btn" type="text">
        <input id="btn" type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-image: url('http://www.aisquared.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/yoga.jpg')
}

#target{
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

**js/jquery**

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $('form').fadeIn(1000)
});
```